# NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist

Tags: jsoup, pom.xml, noclassdeffounderror

I recently updated our pom.xml with new Jsoup dependency version of 1.15.3, since then I am receiving "NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist". Is there a different version that I can use to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 7):

See the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/eabfcdd25d3d1604baaa78d585ea671540a45adf/CHANGES#L313):

> ```
>   * Improvement: renamed the Whitelist class to Safelist, with the
>     goal of more inclusive language. A shim is provided
>     for backwards compatibility (source and binary). This shim is marked as deprecated and will be removed in the
>     jsoup 1.15.1 release.
>     <https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/1464>
> ```

Apparently, `Whitelist` has been removed completely with version *1.15.1*. Use `Safelist` instead or revert to an older version of jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, like commented by Janez Kuhar, use Safelist instead, examples below:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.safety.Safelist;

String[] jsonValue = map.get("json");
String safe = Jsoup.clean(jsonValue[0], Safelist.basic());
String safe = Jsoup.clean(jsonValue[0], Safelist.relaxed()); //this should also work
```